# Run offline scan in chkdsk?

Tags: windows-11, ntfs, chkdsk

**Short form:** How do I "run an offline scan" in chkdsk?

**Details:**

I'm running Win 11 Pro and trying to examine and possibly resurrect an external NTFS drive which appears to be corrupted.  Following the chkdsk docs in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk?tabs=event-viewer

My first attempt was this:

```
>chkdsk f: /scan
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Insufficient storage available to create either the shadow copy storage file or other shadow copy data.

A snapshot error occured while scanning this drive. Run an offline scan and fix.
```

The documentation says that `/forceofflinefix` will "Bypass all online repair; all defects found are queued for offline repair (for example, chkdsk /spotfix).", so that sounds like the right thing.  But I get the same error:

```
>chkdsk f: /scan /forceofflinefix
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Insufficient storage available to create either the shadow copy storage file or other shadow copy data.

A snapshot error occured while scanning this drive. Run an offline scan and fix.
```

So: how do I "run an offline scan"?

Comment: It is working fine here.  Is F:  too small?

Comment: chkdsk is a bad idea for resurrecting drives. explain the issue and what you're trying to accomplish. if you want data back, avoid chkdsk. if not it's simpler to reformat the volume.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen This is the C: drive from another Windows 11 machine.  It won't boot.  When I try to mount it on my Win 11 machine, it puts up a window that it's corrupted.  I want to try to salvage the files that are on the drive.  What tool would you suggest?

Comment: If the data is important, you may wish to get an estimate of recovery from a local recovery agency.

Comment: @fearless_fool, my personal default goto tool is DMDE.

Comment: Do not use chkdsk! — Use [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to get an overview and copy what can be seen on the disk and [ask their support](https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/) for details!. If physical problems are present, you probably should first create a binary copy of the disk by [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/). In bootable Linux Live images it is present quite often. Using `ddrescue` you should **always use the *mapfile* feature**. // Both tools will not manipulate the disk content but will store to a different storage.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer: it needed the /X option.  This worked, and chkdsk managed to repair the volume:

```
>chkdsk f: /X /scan /forceofflinefix
```